# Rails form button that over rides jquery validation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate

I have a multistep form that has validations on both the rails side and jquery side. I was wondering if there was a way to create a button that in essence just "saves" what the user has inputed so they can come back and finish the form when ever.

Comment: Save the partial data into the DB, user retrieves it later, re-saves it?  There are many possibilities.  Have you tried anything at all?  Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how long you want to allow you can save it in the session, or you could use something like this:

https://github.com/vlado/rails_temporary_data

To store it as serialized data which expires (if you choose) after a time and is available to pull it out and update it again and again until you're ready to store it in the model.